# ICACLS IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool = invalid parameter

Tags: windows-server-2008, icacls

The following command:

```
icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":F
```

Constantly returns

```
Invalid parameter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool"
```

For any app pool name on any folder, I'm running this from powershell as admin.

I'm sure this has worked before?

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Dan

Comment: I am having the same issue, it doesn't seem to matter what apppool i enter. I even tried importing the WebAdministration snapin just to see if it was path related to IIS: Please let me know if you find anything

Comment: Invalid syntax likely due to "bug" in documented example ("Securing Resources" section): https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole of the grant argument in quotes:

```
icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool:F"
```

Comment: I don't actually recall what site/server we were having this issue with but this sounds like this would have very likely been the answer and I'll know what to check next time :)

Comment: Relevant to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_Install_the_IntelliTrace_Stand_Alone_Collector -- thank you

Comment: For powershell i ended up with `& icacls $AppDataPath /t /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)F"` wanting it to propagate full access to child folders too